# Postgresql: Where conditions for joined table causing from table results to also not come back

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that will return data from one table where there definitely will be a record and also the sum of time durations from another table that I'm left joining. The problem I'm having is that when no results are found in the joined table, it also causes nothing to come back from the main table as well.

Here is a sample query:

```
select
to_json(a.*) as account,
sum(EXTRACT(epoch from (cr.end_time - cr.start_time) / 3600)) as hours_used,
from accounts a
left join conference_reservations cr on cr.account_id = a.account_id
where a.account_id = 'bdb25b1d-c337-4d7d-aecf-2c1aefd33656'
and cr.status IN ('confirmed', 'completed')
and cr.end_time BETWEEN '2018-04-15 05:00:00' and '2018-05-16 04:59:59'
group by a.*
```

So basically, if no records match the conditions for conference_reservations then i'll get nothing back even though accounts data will be found. I'd rather hours_used be null or 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your conditions on table `cr` to the `ON` clause for that join instead.

```
select
    to_json(a.*) as account,
    sum(EXTRACT(epoch from (cr.end_time - cr.start_time) / 3600)) as hours_used
from accounts a
  left join conference_reservations cr 
     on cr.account_id = a.account_id
        and cr.status IN ('confirmed', 'completed')
        and cr.end_time BETWEEN '2018-04-15 05:00:00' and '2018-05-16 04:59:59'
where a.account_id = 'bdb25b1d-c337-4d7d-aecf-2c1aefd33656'
group by a.*
```

Now you'll filter the `conference_reservations` table before it hits the join, instead of after. This is akin to doing a subquery to get the records from `conference_reservations` that match the filter in your `ON` clause, which would have been another option.

Comment: Thank you a bunch for the solution and explanation!